# JOLT if else and moving the value of the root field to the nested

Tags: java, json, transformation, jolt, isnullorempty

I'm new to Jolt transformations. I will try to describe my case in detail.
I suspect that you will need to combine shift and modify-default operations

HERE: TRANSFORMATION RULE:
if field **detail** have value **(exist and is not"" or null)**
**then map** detail  => updating_field 
else: 
**map** updating_field => updating_field

INPUT

```json
{
  "updating_field": "ACCEPT",
  "channel": {
    "detail": null
  }
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT for e.g. **detail = null** value inside JOLT

```json
{
  "channel": {
    "updating_field": "ACCEPT"
  }
}
```

OTHER INPUT

```json
{
  "updating_field": "ACCEPT",
  "channel": {
    "detail": "normal_value"
  }
}
```

OTHER EXPECTED OUTPUT for e.g. **detail = "**normal_value**" value inside JOLT

```json
{
  "channel": {
    "updating_field": "normal_value"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ***`~`*** operator within a **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation such as

**`"~detail" : "@(2,updating_field)"`**  meaning if `"detail"` does not exist or is null,

then make it be the value of `"updating_field"` after traversing 2 levels (**`:`** and **`{`**) up the tree such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "c*": {
        "~detail": "@(2,updating_field)"
      }
    }
  },
  { // rename the key from "detail" to "updating_field"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "c*": { // the level of "channel" where * stand for abbreviation
        "*": "&1.updating_field"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***first demo*** on the http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ site is :

[image]

the ***second demo*** on the http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ site is :

[image]

**Edit** : If the **null** and empty string (`""`) values should be classifed as in the same category, then use ths **size** function as follows :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "c*": {
        "sz": ["=size(@(1,detail))", 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "c*": {
        "sz": {
          "0": { "@3,updating_field": "&3.updating_field" },
          "*": { "@2,detail": "&3.updating_field" } // else case
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you give me advice how to keep this logic with another fields inside channel block.